# delete all folder except one using batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder named Scripts in current directory Say `C:\QTP\Script\`. I am not sure the folders names and count in that scripts folder. Inside each unknown folder name i have Objective Evidences folder. I want a code that deletes all the files and folders in unknown folders but not objective evidences folder.
EG:

```
Scripts\Folder1\Objective Evidences (this folder1 contains many files too)
Scripts\Folder2\Objective Evidences (This folder2 also contains many files)
```

I am not sure how many folders are present in scripts folder and wat are their names.
I should get the list of folder names present in Scripts folder and delete all files and folder present in it except `Objective Evidences` folder.

Please let me know the batch code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d "C:\QTP\Script\*"') do (
   echo %%~fG | FIND "Objective Evidences" || rd /s /q "%%G"
)
```

Try this...Or this

```
pushd "C:\QTP\Script\"
for /D /R  %%a in (*) do echo "%%~fa" | find "Objective Evidences" || rd /s /q "%%a"
popd
```